# True or False: $\sum_{j=1}^{n} j! =m^2$ where j and m are integer

Tags: number-theory

Does there exist a perfect square of the form $\sum_{j=1}^{n} j!$ where n>3?

I believe that there doesn't exist one how do I proof this?

$m^2 \equiv 0,1,4 \mod 5$

$\sum_{j=1}^{n} j! \equiv 3 \mod 5$

Hence there doesn't exist an n where the sum is a perfect square

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prove that for no n>1 is the sum $(1!)^2+\cdots+(n!)^2$ a perfect square.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/823503/prove-that-for-no-n1-is-the-sum-12-cdotsn2-a-perfect-square)

Comment: @Deepak Here the factorials are not squared.

Comment: @wordsthatendinGRY My apologies, I had missed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Prove $\forall{m}:m^2\equiv0,1,4\pmod5$**

- $m\equiv0\pmod5\implies{m^2}\equiv0\cdot0\equiv0\pmod5$
- $m\equiv1\pmod5\implies{m^2}\equiv1\cdot1\equiv1\pmod5$
- $m\equiv2\pmod5\implies{m^2}\equiv2\cdot2\equiv4\pmod5$
- $m\equiv3\pmod5\implies{m^2}\equiv3\cdot3\equiv9\equiv4\pmod5$
- $m\equiv4\pmod5\implies{m^2}\equiv4\cdot4\equiv16\equiv1\pmod5$

---

**Prove $\forall{n\geq4}:\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}j!\equiv3\pmod5$**

- Observe that $\sum\limits_{j=1}^{4}j!\equiv3\pmod5$
- Let's assume that $\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}j!\equiv3\pmod5$
- Now let's prove that $\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n+1}j!\equiv3\pmod5$
- $\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n+1}j!\equiv(\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}j!)+(n+1)!\equiv3+0\equiv3\pmod5$

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** For  $n=5$ and beyond, our number is congruent to $3$ modulo $5$.

Comment: Actually it is true for n=4 as wekk