# Prove that for no n>1 is the sum $(1!)^2+\cdots+(n!)^2$ a perfect square.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that for no $n>1$ is the sum $(1!)^2+\cdots+(n!)^2$ a perfect square.

I know that $(1!)^2+\cdots+(n!)^2=\sum_{j=1}^{n} (j!)^2$. I also know that the all squares are congruent to 0 or 1 mod 4. But I was experimenting with a couple n's and found that they are equal to 1 mod 4. Is the statement above true?

Answer (score 10):

**Hint:** Work modulo $3$. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Why modulo 3? And what do you mean work?

Comment: By work I mean calculate, just as you did modulo $4$. For $n\ge 2$, your number is congruent to $2$ modulo $3$. A perfect square cannot be congruent to $2$ modulo $3$. Alternately, but with more calculation, we could use $5$ as a modulus. If $n\ge 4$, your number is congruent to $2$ modulo $5$, and no square is congruent to $2$ modulo $5$.

Answer (score 4):

First, show that no perfect square can be equivalent to $7 \pmod{10}$.

From here, note that $n! \equiv 0 \pmod{10}$ for all $n \geq 5$.

Hence, we get:

$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^n(k!)^2 \equiv 1! + (2!)^2 + (3!)^2 + (4!)^2 \equiv 617 \equiv 7 \pmod{10}$$

---

**Edit**: Per Andre's response, working $\pmod{3}$ is a lot easier.  (I chose $10$ since it's super easy to just look at the last digit).  Nevertheless, the strategy is the same: find all the residue classes for perfect squares $\pmod{3}$, then show that  $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n(k!)^2$ does not belong to one of them.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use other modulus to prove that $1!^2+2!^2+3!^2+…+n!^2$ is never a perfect square when $n\geq2$, although using mod $3$ and mod $10$ are always easier.

For example, you can use mod $7$ to see that $1!^2+2!^2+3!^2+…+n!^2$ isn’t a perfect square since when $n\geq7$, $n!\equiv0\bmod7$ and $1!^2+2!^2+3!^2+…7!^2\equiv3\bmod7$, and $3$ is not a quadratic residue mod $7$ since:

$1^2\equiv1\bmod7$

$2^2\equiv4\bmod7$

$3^2\equiv2\bmod7$

$4^2\equiv2\bmod7$

$5^2\equiv4\bmod7$

$6^2\equiv1\bmod7$

$3$ doesn’t appear on above, so $3$ isn’t a quadratic residue mod $7$, or alternatively, $3$ is only a quadratic residue mod $p$ when $p$ is $\pm1$ mod $12$.

Mod $11$ $\textbf{will not work}$, since when $n\geq11$, $1!^2+2!^2+3!^2+…+11!^2\equiv3\bmod7$ and $3$ is a quadratic residue mod $11$, since $5^2\equiv3\bmod7$.

Mod $13$ $\textbf{will also not work}$
because if $n\geq13$, then $1!^2+2!^2+3!^2+…+13!^2\equiv4\bmod13$ and $4$ is a quadratic residue to any mod $n$, since $4$ is a perfect square.

Similarly, this trick $\textbf{will not work for mod $17$}$, since $1!^2+2!^2+3!^2+…+17!^2\equiv15\bmod17$ for all $n\geq17$ and $15$ is quadratic residue mod $17$, since $7^2\equiv15\bmod17$.

But this trick works with mod $19$, because for all $n\geq19$, $1!^2+2!^2+3!^2+…+19!^2\equiv13\bmod19$ and 13 isn’t a quadratic residue mod $19$ since:

$(\pm1)^2\equiv1\bmod19$

$(\pm2)^2\equiv4\bmod19$

$(\pm3)^2\equiv9\bmod19$

$(\pm4)^2\equiv16\bmod19$

$(\pm5)^2\equiv6\bmod19$

$(\pm6)^2\equiv17\bmod19$

$(\pm7)^2\equiv8\bmod19$

$(\pm8)^2\equiv7\bmod19$

$(\pm9)^2\equiv5\bmod19$

Since $13$ doesn’t appear above, $13$ is not quadratic residue mod $19$.